# Ubuntu on a Secondary Drive

Tags: external-hdd

new to the site, not Ubuntu.
I'm currently running Windows 7 on a 1 TB HDD, as it is my primary. I'd like to install Ubuntu on a secondary HDD in which I have an enclosure for. It has Windows 8 on it, but I'm having issues accessing it. I'd like to install on that but remove 8 in the process. I have the Ubuntu installer on a flash drive ready to go, but I'm unsure of how to get the flash drive to install on the external HDD. Any help is appreciated.

On a side note: I've had Ubuntu dual-booted with Windows 7 before, but I seem to have issues with it, that's why I'm doing an external HDD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing Ubuntu on an external hard-disk is similar to how you install it on your internal hard-disk. The changes you need to make are as follows:

- While creating partitions make sure you make them on the external hard-disk. Gparted(the software which helps you create partitions) will show both the devices(internal as well as external hard-disk. It may even show other storage devices connected, if any).
- On the bottom part of the partition creation process, you will be given an option to choose where to load the boot-loader. By default, it may be on the internal hard-disk; change this to the external hard-disk so that you can boot to the OS's in the internal hard-disk even in the absence of the external one.

All other steps remain the same, exactly same.

Comment: Thanks, I had a little bit of an issue with Windows, but it's taking care of now.

Comment: @i08in, will all OS'es installed on all hard drive be listed on grub menu? If not can programs like boot-repair detect them?